# Duplicating form field while editing nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have two classes **Food** and **food_category_price**.

The association looks something like this:

```
has_many :food_category_prices, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_category_prices
```

The foods controller looks something like this for **new**, **create** and **edit** actions.

```
def new
   @food = current_department.foods.new
   @food.food_category_prices.build
end

def edit
   @food = current_department.foods.find(params[:id])
end

 def create
    @food = current_department.foods.create(food_params)
    if @food.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = "Food was successfully created."
      redirect_to foods_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error while adding food"
      render :new
    end
  end
```

My food parameters looks something like this: (I have whitelisted the nested attributes' id)

```
def food_params
    params.require(:food).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image ,food_category_prices_attributes: [:id,:category_id,:extra_price],:category_ids => [])
end
```

The nested form for new action of food is:

```
= form_for @food do |f|
  .field.form-group
    = f.file_field :image, class: 'd-none'
    ......
    ......
    // Nested form from here
  - current_department.categories.where(category_kind: 2).each do |category|
    = f.fields_for :food_category_prices do |g|
      = g.label :category_id, category.name + "("+String(category.price)+")"
      = g.hidden_field :category_id, value: category.id
      = g.label :extra_price, "Extra Price"
      = g.number_field :extra_price
```

**The problem:**

The code words perfeclty fine while creating new food, and nested food_categoy_prices.

The problem is that, when i am editing the form, the attributes are duplicating. The labels such as **extra price** and **category_id** are duplicating.

Comment: The problem is most likely that you are not whitelisting the id attribute for the nested attributes. If there is no id Rails has no way of knowing that the attributes belong to an existing record and will create a new record.  Also `"("+String(category.price)+")"` is very unidiomatic in Ruby. Use `category.price.to_s` or implicit casting. Usually for money though you want to use a method that localizes the output. https://github.com/RubyMoney/money

Comment: In order for us to actually be able to answer this question we need to see the `#create` and `#update` method and your strong parameters method from the controller. `#new` and `#edit` are kind of irrelevant as they just render forms.

Comment: I have added whitelisted "id". This is what my food params looks like:

 params.require(:food).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image ,food_category_prices_attributes: [:id,:category_id,:extra_price],:category_ids => [])

as you can see the food_category_prices_attributes has the :id also permitted

Comment: I have made the changes in the question, specifying the food_params, and the create action